# Access dto value inside a list of dtos

Tags: java, list, dto

I have a json response that comes under this form.

```
"calendarList": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "event": {
                "id": "11",
                "name": "Track the working hours",
                "color": "blue",
                "place": "office",
            }
         },
         {
            "id": "2",
            "event": {
                "id": "12",
                "name": "Finish DTOs",
                "color": "blue",
                "place": "office",
            }
         }
]
```

How can I access the place value? For all of dto objects inside the list the place value will be the same, which is OFFICE, so I just need to access somehow one of the place values.
The list of CalendarDto contains multiple EventDto objects, with the attributes id, name, color and place.

```
final List<CalendarDto> calendarList = calendarService.getCalendars(startDate, endDate);
EventDto eventDto = new EventDto();
    EventSender sender = new EventSender ("EVENTS");
    sender.withData("place", calendarList.stream()  -> this is where I tried to get the value, but it didn't work
        .findFirst(eventDto.getPlace()));
```

Comment: hi, it depends on what framework you use. as you said its an array, so it would be like data[0].event.place , or data.stream().map(DTO::getPlace) and then collect to List of places or what you want

Comment: calendarList.get(0).getEvent().getPlace()?  If your calenderList is mapped properly..

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `filter` and `findFirst` methods of stream.

```
final List<CalendarDto> calendarList = calendarService.getCalendars(startDate, endDate);
EventDto eventDto = new EventDto();
    EventSender sender = new EventSender ("EVENTS");
    sender.withData("place", calendarList.stream()
        .filter(ele -> ele.getPlace().equals(eventDto.getPlace())).findFirst());
```

**Note**:- `ele` into filter method will be object of `CalendarDto` class, here respective method is required to be replaced to get place value.